# Maximal degree of a minimal homogeneous generator smaller than regularity

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-modules

Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a standard graded polynomial ring and $I\subset S$ a homogeneous ideal. Denote $\mathrm{maxdeg}(I)$ the maximal degree of an element in a minimal system of homogeneous generators of $I$. I read that
$$\mathrm{maxdeg(I)}\le\mathrm{reg}(I),$$
where $\mathrm{reg}(I)$ is the regularity of $I$, but I cannot understand why. Can someone please help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What definition of regularity are you working with?

Comment: @ZachTeitler The height of the Betti Table. I know there is another definition in terms of local cohomology, but I never studied it. Is it easier to answer by using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If regularity is defined as the height of the Betti table, then the greatest degree of a generator is the greatest row number of a nonzero entry in the $1$st column (where rows and columns are counted starting from $0$). So the height of the table is at least as great as that.